# vue emit parent not listening to custom event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eventemitter, emit

i am trying to do a emit to do a function call from child to parent.
CodeSandbox of my try.

i dont get why my custom-event is not get listening on parent:
https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-bash-ryq26?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the listener on the component where its come from, not on some div

```
<HelloWorld @whats-up="notMuch" msg="Hello Vue in CodeSandbox!"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should listen to `whats-up` event in HelloWorld component. Code Should be like it

```
<HelloWorld @whats-up="notMuch" msg="Hello Vue in CodeSandbox!"/>
```